# Fiddler only shows traffic from the first page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

I'm trying to simulate a slow connection in Chrome so that I can see how my application behaves under slow speeds. I've downloaded and installed Fiddler 2, and I can run it at the same time as Chrome. When I look at the logs in Fiddler, it captures my start page, being google.com, but it then fails to capture any subsequent requests I make within Chrome, even omitting searches from the same page it started up with. The Fiddler setting to simulate modem speeds also has no effect on Chrome at all. I can close Chrome and re-open it, and the start page will again be captured, but nothing beyond that. It captures from IE just fine, and it even captures the traffic from Desktop Earth trying to retrieve cloud data, but no dice within Chrome.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740313/fiddler-doesnt-capture-traffic-from-chrome), and it has three answers but none selected. The third one has this code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy-server=http={0}:{1};https={0}:{1}", proxyHost, port));
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

...but I have no idea where I would it, as I am completely new to Fiddler. Can someone help me out?

Comment: The implication here is that your Chrome browser is not configured to use the system's default proxy. In Fiddler's LOG tab is there a warning that Chrome is configured via Group Policy to use a specific proxy?

Comment: The most likely culprit then is that you have a Chrome extension that is changing your proxy settings. Some of these include privacy/security tools or those used to circumvent restrictions on where in the world media clips may be played.